# In what edition did Volo first appear?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, lore, books

In what edition did Volo first appear?

I was talking to my friend about *Volo's Guide to Monsters* and he said Volo is from a previous edition. He wasn’t sure which, but said it was not from the 5th edition.

Did Volo first appear in 5th edition or is he from a previous edition, or something like a novel?

Comment: It worth noting that D&D editions share the same timeline and multiverse. Many iconic characters can be met through several editions' sorcebooks. This is also true for Xanathar, Tasha and Mordenkainen.

Comment: @enkryptor that can probably be used in an answer (as amplifying information)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Volothamp Geddarm has been around for more than 20 years, having been [generated by Jeff Grubb](https://mobile.twitter.com/TheEdVerse/status/1087747342726561792) and used by Ed Greenwood in many 2e sourcebooks. The first Volo's Guide book was *[Volo's Guide to Waterdeep](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/16836/Volos-Guide-to-Waterdeep-2e)*, published in 1993, though he was mentioned in the first 2e FR sourcebook *Forgotten Realms Adventures* (1990, page 44). You can find some more detailed information in the [FR fandom wiki page](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Volothamp_Geddarm).

Comment: 1990, so more than 30 years then?

Comment: @milo-p Did you have to remind us that we were getting so old? :-)

Comment: More than 20 years is also accurate =P As is more than a year >.>